# Terribly slow compiles using Xcode 3.2.5 and 3.2.6

Tags: xcode, performance, compiler-construction, xcodebuild

OS X 10.6.7, Xcode 3.2.6 (although 3.2.5 shows the same behavior), Mac Pro - 2 2.4 GHz Quad w/ 8GB of RAM.

We have several of these machines, all but one are running great. A normal clean/build takes about 5-7 minutes. On the "naughty" machine it takes about 30 minutes.

Before starting the build the machine has over 5 GB of RAM free, CPU utilization usage is practically zero. We can't see anything that would be eating up resources.

This is just a pretty simple iOS project (using gcc 4.2) - nothing out of the ordinary. Once we kick off the build the XIBs are compiled quickly. It isn't until we get into the 15th-16th implementation file (.m) that the build process slows to a crawl. At that point we still have tons of RAM available and there is very little CPU usage.

Any recommendations as to how we might track down the issue with this machine?

Thanks!

Comment: I've been seeing something similar to this recently - it only happens on certain projects and there is no obvious cause. I'll be interested to see if you get any useful responses.

Answer (score 1):

Are you building with the release or the debug configuration? Stripping binaries (release configuration) can be pretty time consuming during build times.